# TaskStackBuilder isn't working as expected

Tags: android

What I'm trying to do is create a notification in Android that will open an Activity whenever it is tapped. This activity is called "NotificationsActivity" and its parent is "MainActivity". Whenever the user is presented with NotificationsActivity I want them to be able to press the back button to get to the MainActivity. I've been using the instructions here (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#DirectEntry) to try and get this to work. However, no matter what I try, whenever I press back from the NotificationsActivity the app exits completely. The only issue that I can think of is that my app has a login screen and I have also identified it as a MAIN and LAUNCHER. I don't think this would cause a problem, but that's all I can think of.

To summarize. What I want is:

1. Tap notification
2. Open NotificationsActivity
3. Press Back
4. Open MainActivity

But what I'm getting is:

1. Tap notification
2. Open NotificationsActivity
3. Press Back
4. Exit App

Pertinent code is displayed below.

From AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:noHistory="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".NotificationsActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

And here is my Java code:

```
private void notifyRecordChanges(){
    String notificationText = "test notification";
    Context context = this;

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentText(notificationText);
    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationsActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationsActivity.class);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

EDIT: I removed the LoginActivity class from the project and it made no difference. So, now I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

SECOND EDIT:
To add to Skizo's answer, I had to support the back button on the action bar. Here is the code to handle that. I call "goBack" from both the method override provided by Skizo and the code below.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            goBack();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
private void goBack(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Is there any error on LogCat?

Comment: No errors at all. Usually if the app crashes I don't even see it in the recents list anymore. However, in this situation, it is still showing up in recents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Override the `onBackPressed()` on your `NotificationsActivity`.

Copy&Paste this method :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 // super.onBackPressed();  
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That got me halfway there. It only worked for the hardware back button. The back button on the action bar still exited. I solved that by adding this code. Screw it. I can't get the code to display properly here. I'll edit the post and put it there.

Comment: Shall I add something to my answer? if you solved the problem or I helped to you to solve it feel free yo upvote or mark it as a correct ^^

Comment: Sorry, I was waiting to see if someone else would have an answer as well. While your answer does work, it doesn't really answer the original question. Which is, why isn't my original code working when I'm practically copy/pasting the code from the Android Developer site? Please don't think I do not appreciate your answer. I really do. This got me over a rather annoying hump in my work day. Again, thanks!